Ошибка при использовании HttpClient
Написал небольшой пример для скачивание страницы с помощью HttpClient
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        foo()
    }
}

@Composable
fun foo() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val html = remember { mutableStateOf("HTML") }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.8f)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            text = html.value
        )
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).weight(0.2f),
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    html.value = async { getHtml() }.await()
                }
            }, content = {
                Text(text = "GO")
            }

        )
    }
}

suspend fun getHtml(): String =
    coroutineScope {
        val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build()
        val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://webcode.me/"))
            .build()
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).join().body()
    }

Пример работает, но если скомпилировать в exe файл с помощью команды gradlew createDistributable то при запуске exe файла получаю ошибку java/net/http/HitpClient

Подскажите как это исправить.

Возможно вот это поможет: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md#configuring-included-jdk-modules

@Eugene Krivenja modules("java.net.http") работает , спасибо
